# Find exponent of prime $p$ in prime factorization of a number $x$

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Say we have a number $x$ such that
$$ x = a^{r}.b^{s}.c^{t}.p^{u} $$
Is there a formula or method which can directly give me the exponent of a particular prime in this prime factorization.

For small $x$ calculating it is not a problem but when $x$ is of the order of $10^{8}$ finding the exponent of a particular prime becomes tough.

e.g. For $p$ it should give $u$, for $a$ it should give $r$ and so on.

If somehow $x$ can be represented as $\frac{a!}{b!}$ then also it can be done.

Comment: Um... you *look* at it.  What the heck do you mean be formula or method?  If you know that $x = a^t*b^s*c^t*d^u$ then you have *already* done all the work.  What more is there that can be known.

Comment: What if x is a huge number then finding all the prime factors of it just to get the exponent of one particular prime is a waste of computational power I guess. Was looking for an efficient method like there is for factorials.

Comment: But the questions not well formed.  How do we know $x = a^rb^sc^tp^u$ and given that the answer can't be expressed as anything simpler than the highest power that q goes into a times r plus the highest power q goes into b times s plus...  We only have a method for factorials because that is a method of what the number is.  In this case.... you do prime factorization by... doing prime factorization.  Unless I'm missing something, not only does the question make no sense, there is no question being asked.

Comment: It's like asking is there a general way to find the solutions to $f(x) = 0$ if we don't know what $f$ is.

Comment: The question seems well-formed to me, if you take the statement $x = a^r b^s c^t p^u$ as a restatement of the fundamental theorem of algebra, and the question to be whether there is an algorithm/formula to get the exponent of a particular prime in this decomposition. Which there is, and you don't need to fully factorize, either.

Comment: The question is well-formed to me. I had the exact same question and found this by Google.

Answer (score 3):

Given $x$ and $p$, just divide $x$ by $p$ repeatedly and count how many times it gives no remainder.

Comment: Agreed - this is a very simple way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [FredAkalin's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2313164/401264), we can write an algorithm in pseudocode as follows:

```
prime_exp(x,p):
    count = 0
    while x mod p is 0: (loop while x is exactly divisible by p)
        count += 1 (increase exponent value by 1)
        x = x / p (divide x by p)
    return count
```

We can run this on the number $364=2^2\times 7\times 13$:

```
prime_exp(364,2)
```

We first have

```
count = 0
```

We compute `364 mod 2 = 0`

So now we have

```
count = 1
x = 364 / 2 = 182
```

We loop back round and compute `182 mod 2 = 0`

So now we have

```
count = 2
x = 182 / 2 = 91
```

We loop back round again and compute `91 mod 2 = 1` so we exit the while loop

We therefore return the value of `count = 2`

We can see this is equal to the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorisation of $364$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion: Compute powers $p$, $p^2$, $p^4$, … $p^{2^n}$, … by repeated squaring (note that each of these is the square of the preceding one), until $p^{2^{n+1}}\nmid x$. Then repeat the procedure with $x_1=x/p^{2^n}$, and so forth, until you arrive at a number not divisible by $p$. Now $a=2^{n+1}+\cdots$, where $\cdots$ is the sum of powers of $2$ obtained in each subsequent step.